# how can i hardCode the Month For DatePicker Calender

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

in my application i use "DatePick Calender".i want to hardcode for "Month".supose
i select"06/30/2011" then i want to get "12/30/2011" like this. please help anyone as early as possible.

My Trying Code is

```
  <script type="text/javascript"
> src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
>         <script type="text/javascript"
> src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
>         <script type="text/javascript"
> src="js/jquery.datepick.js"></script>
>         <script type="text/javascript"
> src="js/jquery.datepick.ext.js"></script>
>         <style type="text/css">
>             @import "css/jquery.datepick.css";
>         </style>
>     
>       <script type="text/javascript">
>     
>             $(function () {
>                 $('#txtPaymentDate').datepick({
>                     onDate: $.datepick.noWeekends, showTrigger:
> '#calImg'
>                 });
>             });
>          
>         </script>
>     
>     
>      <asp:TextBox ID="txtPaymentDate" runat="server" Width="132px"
> onBlur="Tab();" 
>                                 Font-Size="X-Small"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: i'm a little confused. in your example, are you saying that regardless of the month the user chooses a date in (like 06/30/2011, user chose a date in june), you want your code to automatically change the month to something  you hardcode in (in your case, 12 for december). is this accurate?

Comment: hi 'wolv' thank u for u r replay.in my code i want to hardcode the month. With out distrubing of Date,year given by the user.

Comment: Did you find the answer ? Thanks to share :)

Answer (score 0):

Use dateFormat option

```
$("selector").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy' });
```

Where mm = hardcoded month ...